# How to compare same text field in 2 different table (no related) and save as new table

Tags: ms-access, excel-2007

i need to compare table users and table accounts.

Both have the same usercode (a textfield ) but there's no relation between them.

Usercode (must be 11 char text) from :

- table account is "perfect" (i mean correct)
- users most of time loose some of required 11 chars

I need to seach into accounts usercode looking for something similar to users (min. 9 or 10 char, no matter if from beginning or from the middle).
 **I only need what doesn't match, not what match.**

The output must be:

- id from users
- id from accounts
- usercode from accounts
- usercode from users

I can do that in access or excel, decide you what's better!

example of users

```
iduser        usercode_user
1             1a2b3c4d5
2             123456789a
```

example of accounts

```
idaccount     usercode_accounts
55            1a2b3c4d5e6
87            a123456789a
```

example of results

```
iduser    idaccount     usercode_user      usercode_accounts
1         55            1a2b3c4d5          1a2b3c4d5e6
2         87            123456789a         a123456789a
```

Comment: as you can see i've edited and add some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.iduser, a.idaccount, u.usercode_user, a.usercode_accounts
FROM users AS u, accounts AS a
WHERE (((a.usercode_accounts) Like "*" & [u].[usercode_user] & "*"));
```

That query could be painfully slow if your tables contain many thousands of rows.  But it does produce your desired output with the sample data you provided.

If you're running the query with ADO, use the ANSI wildcard character % instead of *.

Or you could use the ALike comparison like this, and the query will work with either ADO or DAO.

```
WHERE (((a.usercode_accounts) ALike "%" & [u].[usercode_user] & "%"))
```

**Edit**: Your sample data didn't include any of the same usercodes in users and accounts.  But to exclude exact matches, use this:

```
SELECT u.iduser, a.idaccount, u.usercode_user, a.usercode_accounts
FROM users AS u, accounts AS a
WHERE
    (((a.usercode_accounts)<>[u].[usercode_user]
    And (a.usercode_accounts) ALike "%" & [u].[usercode_user] & "%"));
```

Comment: Right.  I designed and tested it with Access 2003.  Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.  Try another question and tell us what field(s) you want to update in users, what value(s) you will update with, and whether you're talking about rows where usercode_user are exact matches to usercode_accounts or "ALike" matches.

Comment: I just like to let your query as update for user table and update only usercode_user from usercode_accounts. If you can't tell me here it's ok anyway.

Comment: The performance issue can be addressed by adding criteria to eliminate comparisons that won't need to be done, i.e., the ones where the values are not equal. I would contemplate doing that with a LEFT JOIN, to get the list of nonmatching records, and then run your WHERE clause on the result. But I haven't tried the SQL, so there may be something that causes that not to work.